# Receiving a broadcasted Intent in Appium

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, appium, ui-automation

I am trying to use Appium to run tests on an Android device where the app we are interfacing with provides an API via the Intents library.  We can send Intents with commands to it like "sendMessage", "pressKeyDown", etc.

One of the requirements is that this app also wants to broadcast Intents back to us as a way of providing a response.

We were considering using the Appium libraries as it would require a lot less work in our current  architecture.  However, I don't see a way in Appium to register a receiver.  Are my eyes deceiving me or is this not a thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Appium supports it out of the box. It is not available via general [API](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/api/), but you can give it a try via [mobile:command](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/index.html) interface simply running adb shell command.

If you will go this way, you probably need to [start Appium with security args](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/security/index.html)
Should not be a problem while running on self hosted machines, but could be not available on 3rd party services.